# jsonp callback not firing from iPhone simulator with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

I have an HTML5/JS app backed by ASP.NET WebAPI.  The WebAPI is running on my windows PC IIS for now and the client app is running on a separate mac device on the same network.

When I run the application via Safari on the Mac, this works fine (callbacks okay, etc...) - same goes for browsers on my Windows PC.

After I build the PhoneGap app and load in XCode then try to run the simulator, I get errors (jQuery###### never called), the typical callback is never called error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added your server to whitelist?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

> iOS
>
> Details
>
> Open Cordova.plist. In Xcode, it is found at AppName/Supporting
>   Files/Cordova.plist In the directory, it is found at
>   AppName/Cordova.plist Add a new String value under the ExternalHosts
>   key. We recommend using Xcode to avoid editing raw XML. Domain
>   protocols (e.g. http:// and https://) are not supported by iOS.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what it was.  I figured it out, but will mark this as the answer.